# Showing progress bar until image loads. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, future, flutter-http

I want to make a register screen with captcha and the api I am using is sending the raw image bytes and in header a secret value to validate the captcha. I want to take the bytes from http.get and show them to image.memory in my register screen and also save the timeStamp for submitting data.

---

I have a register.dart file where I have all the UI. Then a getCaptcha.dart file containing a future function to get the captcha and header.

[image]

---

[image: getCaptcha.dart]

---

[image: register.dart initstate]

---

[image: register.dart problem]

---

Comment: It is preferred to enter code snippets and not screen shots. Ideally you also exclude any boilerplate not necessary for understanding your issue

Comment: What you're asking isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry @Eren , I mean until I get the response/bytes I want to display a progress bar..

Comment: @Alok-P it is said down below but you should use FutureBuilder. The example code on the docs should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can try FutureBuilder to show progress until you get response from API.

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: Future<String>.delayed(
                Duration(seconds: 5),
                () => 'Data Loaded',
              ),
              builder: (context, snapShot) {
                return !state.recentSearchCalled
                    ? buildLoadingUi(context)
                    : buildSearchUI(context, state);
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "loading" status

```dart
setState(() { isloading = true });
await getCaptcha();
setState(() { isloading = false });
```